# IllegalStateException: Cannot Subscrie.Processor is already terminated

Tags: java, amqp, azure-eventhub, illegalstateexception

I created a new eventhub and trying to publish messages to eventHubA. When I am trying to send messages to eventhub , I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: namespace[xxxxx] entityPath[xxxxx]:
> Cannot subscribe. Processor is already terminated at
> com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpChannelProcessor.subscribe(AmqpChannelProcessor.java:217)

Below is the code snippet i am using:

```
public void send(Response response) {
        String responseInString = JsonHandlingUtil.objectToJsonString(response);

        EventData eventData = new EventData(responseInString);
        // create a batch
        EventDataBatch eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

        // try to add the event from the array to the batch
        if (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {
            // if the batch is full, send it and then create a new batch
            producer.send(eventDataBatch);
            eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

            // Try to add that event that couldn't fit before.
            if (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event is too large for an empty batch. Max size: "
                        + eventDataBatch.getMaxSizeInBytes());
            }
        }
        // send the last batch of remaining events
        if (eventDataBatch.getCount() > 0) {
            producer.send(eventDataBatch);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
```

I have defined the eventhubProducerClient as a Bean.

```
 @Bean
    public EventHubProducerClient eventHubProducerClient() {
        return new EventHubClientBuilder()
                .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
                .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
                .buildProducerClient();
    }
```

Below is my gradle dependencies

```
>    //eventhub
>         implementation 'com.azure:azure-messaging-eventhubs:5.7.0'
>         implementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.4.6'
```

Comment: What's the lifetime of your producer client?   Is the bean representing a singleton instance within the scope of your application or is it transient?    I'm noticing that you're calling `producer.close()` in your `send` method, which would invalidate your producer instance if the bean is managing it as a singleton.

Comment: The pattern that you're using to send is odd for what your scenario appears to be;  you're creating a batch to hold a single event, but managing that batch as if it's in a loop that produces multiple events.    Since you're sending a single event, you may want to consider not using a batch and, instead, just calling the overload that accepts a set of messages.

Comment: @JesseSquire may be can you please explain with example or a small code snippet that your trying to say ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is in response to my second comment.   Specifically, I'm speaking about this overload:  `send(Iterable<EventData> events)` docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubproducerclient.send?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventhubproducerclient-send(java-lang-iterable(com-azure-messaging-eve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343840/how-to-configure-producer-close-in-eventhub) question, it would appear that the root cause has been confirmed as the `producer.close()` call in the `send` method.

Since it appears that he producer is being managed as a singleton by the application, the mitigation would be to call `close` at the point when events are no longer going to be published, such as when the application is shutting down.