# How to configure Producer.close() in Eventhub

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

Here is the following scenario. I have a Event Producer which publishes events. I referred the mircosoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send

According to my usecase, I have a bean which would create the eventhubProducerClient connection at start of my application. However , the producer.close() in my send method (from above documentation) is called after each event is sent. So, this leads to close of my producer and when I would like to send the next event, there is already an exception that the producer is terminated.

What is the best way to handle the producer.close (). can I leave the producer open ? Wouldnt that cause a memory leak ? Is there a strategy on how I can handle this ?
any lead would be helpful

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each of the Event Hubs client types is safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime of the application, which is best practice when events are being published or read regularly. The clients are responsible for efficient management of network, CPU, and memory use, working to keep usage low during periods of inactivity. Calling `close` on a client is required to ensure that network resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.