# Azure event Hub connection is closed error

Tags: amqp, azure-eventhub

I see something like the following error while using azure event hub to send event message. But as I see in the azure portal, the metric shows that the event message is sent to the event hub. So I'm puzzled by what this error message means.

As I read from the azure doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-amqp-troubleshoot), it said "You see the following error on the AMQP connection when all links in the connection have been closed because there was no activity (idle) and a new link hasn't been created in 5 minutes."

The doc also said "You can avoid them by making send/receive calls on the connection/link, which automatically recreates the connection/link."

What should be done regarding this error message ? As although the event message can be sent, I worry whether there may be any potential issue there.

```
" Error{condition=amqp:connection:forced, description='The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 300000 milliseconds and is closed by container 'LinkTracker'. TrackingId:00000000000000000000000000000000000_G21, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-03-06T17:32:00', info=null} "
```

I once tried that if I call the `close()` method in `EventHubProducerClient` (by refer to sample code in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send), this error seems not appear again. However, if doing so, when every time need to send the event, it will mean need to create a new `EventHubProducerClient`. I'm not sure if this may create another problem (like time required to create the new `EventHubProducerClient`, and memory consumption) if creating a new `EventHubProducerClient` for every send event, as there can be many events to send.

On another search, I found in [How to configure Producer.close() in Eventhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343840/how-to-configure-producer-close-in-eventhub), that it is recommended to close the producer client after using it.

However, if the above error message is actually not an error, whether to close or not may not matter.

Comment: Got some further update on the question, not sure if it may related to the close() method. However, based on the provided answer, the log is only a reflection of the connection being automatically closed after idle for quite a while, and so is not an error by nature.

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-service-bus-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues)